# A bounded sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent if $\lim(\sup(x_n))=\lim(\inf(x_n))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

My attempt:
Let $v$ be the $\lim(\sup(x_n))$.Then according to the definition ,
There will be infinite number of elements that will lie in the interval $(v-e,v]$where $e>0$.

$v-2e<x_n \le v$ for all $n \ge N$.

Let $v_1$ be the $\lim(\inf(x_n))$.Then according to the definition ,
There will be infinite number of elements that will lie in the interval $[v_1,v_1+2e)$where $e>0$.

$v_1 \le x_n < v_1+2e$ for all $n \ge N_1$.

Let $K=\max\{N,N_1\}$

AS $v=v_1$.

$2v-2e < 2x_n < 2v + 2e$.

$v-e < x_n < v+e .$ for all $ n \ge K$.

Hence the sequence converges to v .
I have written the proof based on my intuition.  Is it rigorous and also is it correct?

Comment: The sequence $x_n=0$ gives $v=0$ but there are no elements in $(v-\epsilon,v)$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: So the interval should be $(v-e,v]$ ?

Comment: No. I don't know what you are trying to do with the interval. There is a much more straightforward way based on the definition of $\limsup, \liminf$.

Comment: If $v$ is the lim(sup($x_n$)) then there are infinitely many terms of $x_n$ such that $v-e<x_n$ holds where $e>0$ and there are at most finitely many terms such that $v+e<x_n$ holds.So I just used it to write that there are infinitely many terms in the interval $(v-e,v]$ or such that $v-e<x_n \le v$holds.

Comment: Notation $\lim(\sup(x_n))$ is nonstandard.  There is a common notation $\limsup x_n$, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestion by Copper.hat .

$(x_n)$ is bounded.

$a_n:= \inf \{x_k: k \ge n \}$;

$b_n:= \sup \{x_k: k\ge n \}$;

$a_n \le b_n$;

$\lim_{n} a_n=a=\lim_{n} b_n$;

$a_n =\inf \{x_k|k\ge n \} \le x_n \le$ $\sup \{x_k| k\ge n \}=b_n$;

$a=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n \le \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}x_n \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n =a.$

Hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n = a$

Comment: seth.Thank.you.Greetings.